# why $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are zero-dimensional spaces?

Tags: general-topology

why     $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$  are zero-dimensional spaces ?

**My attempt** : Definition of  zero-dimensional spaces:

A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be zero-dimensional if there is a basis for the topology consisting of clopen sets

we know that in discrete space all basis for the topology consisting of clopen sets.so here i can said that obviously $\mathbb{Z}$ will be  zero-dimensional spaces since $\mathbb{Z}$ induce discrete topology

But im confused about $\mathbb{Q}$  because it is neither closed nor open

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Z$ have a topology induced from the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. And $\Bbb Q$ is both closed and open in $\Bbb Q$. Try showing that the set of open intervals with irrational endpoints intersected with $\Bbb Q$ is a basis of clopen sets.

Comment: For any topological space $X$, the whole space is both closed and open, so that's not an issue. You need to find a basis for $\mathbb Q$ so that each basis element is both closed and open. Do you know any bases for $\mathbb Q$? Can they be adjusted?

Comment: okks  u mean $(\sqrt a,\sqrt b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ @CheerfulParsnip

Comment: There are more irrationals than just square roots...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b)\mid a, b \in \Bbb P\}$ forms a base for the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ (where $\Bbb P = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ is the set of irrationals).

For each $(a,b) \in \mathcal{B}$ it’s clear that $(a,b) \cap \Bbb Q = [a,b]\cap \Bbb Q$ and so the set $\{B \cap \Bbb Q\mid B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ is a base for the subspace topology of $\Bbb Q$ that consists of closed-and-open (clopen) sets.

Comment: Can we alternatively find for each $x$ some $c_1, c_2 \in P$, such that $x \in (c_1,c_2) \subset (a,b)$ and reason that $(c_1, c_2)$ is clopen since it's an interval and it's complement is also open $Q$?

Comment: @СССР $(c_1, c_2)$ has complement $(-\infty, c_1) \cup (c_2, +\infty)$ in $\Bbb Q$ so is clopen directly.

Comment: Great, I guess in a similar way one can prove $ind(\underline P) = 0$ then.

Comment: @СССР $\partial (a,b)= \emptyset$ when $a,b$ are rational and the interval is taken in $\Bbb P$. So by definition $\textrm{ind}(\Bbb P)=0$.